# ": No such file or directory" in executing shell file

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I have created a file, 1.sh, which has the content

> c++ -c 1.cpp
>
> c++ 1.o -o 1

In the same folder including 1.sh, there is a file called 1.cpp.

When I execute 1.sh using ./1.sh, the system informed me

> : No such file or directory
>
> c++: fatal error: no input files
>
> compilation terminated.

My question is, what is wrong with 1.sh?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1.sh is probably with CRLF line ending.
What does `file 1.sh` say?

Regardless, try to install dos2unix and run `dos2unix 1.sh`. This will convert to CR endings, which is what POSIX tools expect.

Comment: file 1.sh  says, 1.sh: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators and sudo apt-get install dos2unix works!!

Comment: Just, what is CRLF line ending? ... I tried to search, but did get the point :(

Comment: @Rodriguez under Windows text lines end with `\r\n` but under UNIX it's just `\n` and the stray `\r` is bothering you. It's an invisible control character.

Comment: Thank you! I am using bash on Ubuntu on windows!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the code file (in this case 1.cpp) in your current working directory. If the code file is in a different directory, you need to specify where in the command. For example

`g++ some/other/folder/1.cpp -o 1.o`

Comment: you can also add -I . It lets you add include search paths to the command line.